# ssh pseudoterminal special character problems

Tags: ssh, tty, pseudoterminal, pts

So I have the following situation: I have a host that exhibits unexpected behavior when using `ssh -t` combined with tmux.

If I call `ssh -t my-problem-host tmux` non-ascii characters (e.g. `€`) are displayed as `_`. If I connect without calling tmux, there is no problem.

For example `ssh -t my-problem-host bash` followed by manually entering tmux is OK, while `ssh -t my-problem-host bash tmux` is not OK.

Other strange behavior outside of tmux: If I use `ssh -t my-problem-host  vim` and enter a special character, I get the special character and a space. If I use `ssh -t my-problem-host mc` and type a special character, I get two questions `??`.

I also have this problem only with a single host and would like to know what causes this and how this can be fixed. Essentially `ssh -t` seems to cause problems, the host seems to have a strange pseudo-terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to edit `/etc/default/locale`. It contained `LANG=C`. I changed it to `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

If I used ssh without `-t`, LANG was set for bash, but with `-t` LANG was set to C for another program such as tmux or vim.